# Shortcuts to 'Move to the Next Sheet' with Brave Browser on Mac

Tags: macos, google-chrome, google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts, brave-browser

I just switched from using Google Chrome to Brave and I normally use Google Sheets for work. However, I have searched in Google and not yet find a way to use shortcuts for **'Move to the Next Sheet' with Brave Browser on Mac.**

In Google Chrome, I normally use Option + Arrow up/down, but not work with Brave

How do we solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

A solution found.

```
press fn + Shift + command with arrow up or down.
```